# W3C Widget API support on ChromeOS apps

Tags: google-chrome-app, w3c, google-chrome-os

Is it possible to run W3C Widgets on ChromeOS packaged apps?

> https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/widgets
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-apis

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it’s not possible to run W3C Widgets on ChromeOS packaged apps.

The W3C Widgets specs are obsolete specs that were never widely adopted. The only major browser engine that ever implemented support for W3C Widgets was (old Presto-based) Opera.

Outside of that the only other implementations were in a handful of other obscure footnotes in history: Apache Wookie, Aplix Web Runtime, OBIGO X10, and Borqs WRT.

And all that was years ago now. Details are in [the W3C implementation report for the Widgets spec](https://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/widgets/imp-report/).